# Why is there a need for parenthesis on the right side of the equal sign when assigning a Map variable?

Tags: apex, map, compile-error

I have a question regarding the second portion of this code snippet. When using the  "Map<String, Object>" assignments, why is it that I have to use parentheses around the  Map<String, Object> on the right side of the equal sign, but not on the left side. When I remove the parens I get an error.

Is there a name for this concept/syntax requirement? I would like to look further into what other situations I may need to use this kind of syntax when assigning variables.

```
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint('https://th-apex-http-callout.herokuapp.com/animals/1');
        request.setMethod('GET');
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);

            Map<String, Object> TopLevel = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
            Map<String, Object> animal = (Map<String, Object>) TopLevel.get('animal');
            String animalName = string.valueOf(animal.get('name'));
```

Comment: This is called `casting`

Answer (score 1):

Every left parenthesis in your code example has a closing right parenthesis.
Count each left and you'll see that there is a right.
So you are getting an error when removing the necessary right, because that causes an extra left that has no closing parenthesis.

In the line `Map<String, Object> animal = (Map<String, Object>) TopLevel.get('animal');` you are casting the value of TopLevel as a Map<String, Object>.
In the line `Map<String, Object> animal = (Map<String, Object>) TopLevel.get('animal');` you are casting the value of TopLevel again as a Map<String, Object>.
And in the last line, you are taking the value of animal['name'] and are casting it to a string, but are doing it in a way that you can do with strings that you can't do with other things like objects.

TL;DR - You have to close every opening parenthesis, which is what you've done in your code.

Answer (score 1):

The bit where we put a class in parentheses is called [casting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_casting.htm#:%7E:text=This%20means%20that%20Apex%20enables,one%20data%20type%20to%20another.&text=Therefore%2C%20it%20is%20a%20subclass%20of%20that%20class.). This is required because Apex is a [strongly typed language](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_about.htm&type=5). In a strongly typed language, the compiler makes checks to see if certain things are legal or not. For example, if I write:

```
Integer x = '5';
```

The compiler tells me that I can't do this, because `'5'` is a `String`, but the data type is an `Integer`. The act of casting tells the compiler that we "know" what we're doing and want the compiler to ignore the apparent data conversion problem. At this point, assuming the compiler allows it, we can still run in to "runtime" conversion problems. For example, I can write:

```
Object o = '5';
Integer i = (Integer)o;
```

Here, we tell the compiler that `o` should be assumed to be an `Integer`, and it will happily accept our explanation. Note that a looser check is still applied; we cannot cast a `String` directly to an `Integer`, because there is never a situation where this is a legal conversion. You can only cast between types that are either parents or children of each other. The code above works because Object is the parent of all data types.

In your example, `JSON.deserializeUntyped` returns an `Object`. As such, it may be a `List<Object>`, `Map<String, Object>`, or a primitive of some sort (`String`, `Boolean`, or `null`). We must tell the compiler to make an assumption about the data type in order to compile the rest of the code. As long as the runtime class matches this expectation, the code will run fine. If you choose the wrong type, you get a TypeException (which you can try-catch on).

You may also choose to use `instanceof` to determine which path to take:

```
Object TopLevel = JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
if(topLevel instanceof Map<String, Object>) {
  // Do something with a Map
} else if(topLevel instanceof List<Object>) {
  // Do something with a list
} else if(topLevel instanceOf String) {
  // Do something with a String
} else if(topLevel instanceof Boolean) {
  // Do something with a Boolean
}
```

This allows you to handle a variety of responses depending on what was received. Of course, in practical terms, you'll almost always know it'll be one or two types, but this sort of feature detection can be useful for generic algorithms that involve casting.

We can also use casting in places other than assignment:

```
Object a = 1, b = 2;
System.debug((Integer)a+(Integer)b);
```

In this case, we have two Objects (that are secretly `Integer` values), and then we cast those values so we can perform Integer addition.